# Update dict with extra values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following that converts data (show) from 1 format to another, this used to work until trakt.tv updated their api.

What i need now is all episodes numbers for each season inside one season number like so

`"seasons": [{"number": 1, "episodes": [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}]}]}]`

The converted data should finally look like

`"shows": [{"title": "The Walking Dead", "year": 2010, "ids": {"tvdb": 153021, "imdb": "tt1520211", "tmdb": 1402, "tvrage": 25056}, "seasons": [{"number": 1, "episodes": [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}]}]}]`

The original data (show) looks like

`{'episodes': [{'episode': 0, 'season': 1}, {'episode': 1, 'season': 1}, {'episode': 2, 'season': 1}], 'imdbnumber': '260449', 'title': 'Vikings'}`

The title, year and ids sections are ok, If i run the code as it is now i end up with multiple season 1 (1 for each episode)

```
def convert_YAMJ_show_to_trakt(show):
#"shows": [{"title": "The Walking Dead", "year": 2010, "ids": {"tvdb": 153021, "imdb": "tt1520211", "tmdb": 1402, "tvrage": 25056}, "seasons": [{"number": 1, "episodes": [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}]}]}]
trakt_show = {'ids':{}}

if 'imdbnumber' in show:
    if show['imdbnumber'].startswith('tt'):
        trakt_show['ids']['imdb'] = show['imdbnumber']
    else:
        trakt_show['ids']['tvdb'] = show['imdbnumber']

if 'tvdb' in show:
    trakt_show['ids']['tvdb'] = show['tvdb']

if 'imdb' in show:
    trakt_show['ids']['imdb'] = show['imdb']

if 'title' in show:
    trakt_show['title'] = show['title']

if 'episodes' in show and show['episodes']:
    for episode in show['episodes']:
        if 'date' in episode:
            #ep = {'episode': episode['episode'], 'season': episode['season'], 'watched_at': episode['date']}
            ep = {"seasons": [{"number": episode['season'], "episodes": [{"number": episode['episode']}]}]}
        else:
            #ep = {'episode': episode['episode'], 'season': episode['season']}
            ep = {"seasons": [{"number": episode['season'], "episodes": [{"number": episode['episode']}]}]}

        #if 'playcount' in episode:
        #     ep['plays'] = episode['playcount']

        #trakt_show['seasons'].append(ep)
        trakt_show.append(ep)
return trakt_show
```

Comment: so for these input `{'episodes': [{'episode': 0, 'season': 1}, {'episode': 1, 'season': 1}, {'episode': 2, 'season': 1}], 'imdbnumber': '260449', 'title': 'Vikings'}`, I am getting output `{'seasons': [{'episodes': [{'number': 2}], 'number': 1}], 'ids': {'tvdb': '260449'}, 'title': 'Vikings'}` So what you want in output??

Comment: The first for will work, the next time it will just add another season entry ````{'seasons': [{'episodes': [{'number': 1}], 'number': 1}],{'seasons': [{'episodes': [{'number': 2}], 'number': 1}],{'seasons': [{'episodes': [{'number': 3}], 'number': 1}]````

Comment: still not getting, you want out as `{'seasons': [[{'episodes': [{'number': 0}], 'number': 1}], [{'episodes': [{'number': 1}], 'number': 1}], [{'episodes': [{'number': 2}], 'number': 1}]], 'ids': {'tvdb': '260449'}, 'title': 'Vikings'}`  or ping me on skype vivek.igp

Comment: I am trying to get output like, ````{"seasons": [{"number": 1, "episodes": [{"number": 1}, {"number": 2}, {"number": 3}]}]}]```` So need a single season 1 with all episodes from season 1, and the same for every season (a single season 2 with all episodes from season 2 and so on)

Comment: yes got it now. doing..

Comment: Can you check I am give right solution or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:-

1. I have change for loop logic. Created `dictionary` which have `key` as `season number` and `value` is `list` of `episode number.
2. Final created output structure from dictionary.

code:

```
show = {
        'episodes': [
                    {'episode': 0, 'season': 1}, {'episode': 1, 'season': 1}, {'episode': 2, 'season': 1},
                    {'episode': 0, 'season': 2}, {'episode': 1, 'season': 2}, {'episode': 2, 'season': 2},
                ], 
            'imdbnumber': '260449', 'title': 'Vikings'
        }


trakt_show = {'ids':{}}

if 'imdbnumber' in show:
    if show['imdbnumber'].startswith('tt'):
        trakt_show['ids']['imdb'] = show['imdbnumber']
    else:
        trakt_show['ids']['tvdb'] = show['imdbnumber']
try:
    trakt_show['ids']['tvdb'] = show['tvdb']
except:
    pass
try:
    trakt_show['ids']['imdb'] = show['imdb']
except:
    pass
try:
    trakt_show['title'] = show['title']
except:
    pass

if 'episodes' in show and show['episodes']:
    ep = {}
    for episode in show['episodes']:
        try:
            ep[episode["season"]].append(episode["episode"])
        except:
            ep[episode["season"]] = [episode["episode"]]

    ep1 = {"seasons":[]}
    for i in ep:
        tmp = dict()
        tmp["number"] = i
        tmp["episodes"] = []
        for j in ep[i]:
            tmp["episodes"].append({"number":j})
        ep1["seasons"].append(tmp)
    trakt_show.update(ep1)
print trakt_show
```

Output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop$ python 2.py 
{'seasons': [{'episodes': [{'number': 0}, {'number': 1}, {'number': 2}], 'number': 1}, {'episodes': [{'number': 0}, {'number': 1}, {'number': 2}], 'number': 2}], 'ids': {'tvdb': '260449'}, 'title': 'Vikings'}
```

Comment: That does just what i was after, thanks for finding a solution to my issue.

Comment: its ok, If you have any problem then I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.